# How to configure relative datasource file for SQLite?

Tags: spring, sqlite, maven

I'm trying to configure a SQLite database for an Spring Web App. The thing is that I'm not able to reach the database file that I've created in src/main/resources using a relative path.

I've tried several configurations for the jdbc url but none of them worked:

```
jdbc:sqlite:mydb.sqlite (here I changed the file location to the project root)
jdbc:sqlite:${jdbc.url} (here I passed the url as a parameter thru PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer)
jdbc:sqlite:src/main/resources/mydb.sqlite
```

A weird thing that I realized about is that the app is using Eclipse's directory as the directory to find the database file. I mean, when I put `jdbc:sqlite:mydb.sqlite` it creates an mydb.sqlite on Eclipse's directory not in project's root.

Answer (score 0):

Check the  JVM system property named "user.dir" and set the path relative to it. It is the "current dir" of your java app. It can be different if you run from eclipse or from cmd line or inside webserver(tomcat).

So, System.getPropery("user.dir") will tell you current dir of your running app. Set the path to db relative to that directory.

I would say eclipse does not run your app from the project dir, as it should by default. Check your "run" settings in the eclipse.